# jQuery in Wordpress - Unable to solve the problem: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I know there are lots of questions already submitted for this topic, but I have been stuck for hours. I CANNOT get jQuery working with WordPress. I have checked and double checked and read countless articles on this. Any help or advice would be very welcome.

- I have only just started on a new WordPress site, so there are minimal plugins.
- I am using theme: twentyseventeen and a child theme based on this.

On the test page I am using, in the console I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Here is my code:

The script file is called testjQuery.js. The contents are:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

The contents of the child-theme functions.php file are:

```
    function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('testjQuery', home_url() . '/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/resources/js/testjQuery.js', array('jquery'));
}
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

I am using a PAGE with a "test template". Here are the contents:

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: temp_jQuery
Template Post Type: Page
/?>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://stunninghikes.com/evenbetterhikes/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/resources/js/testjQuery.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of where to place what. No joy. This is the first time I have tried to add jQuery to my site, so I am sure I have made a beginners error -  I am a beginner.

Comment: you don't have jquery in your "test template" file. "test template" is just a pure html, where not loading any wordpress file. use minimum `get_header()` function in your template. check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#using-template-files

Comment: also, even after it you will get `$ is not defined`. so change all `$` in your js with `jQuery`, or use something like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})`

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you. It also makes sense why it did not work - I was trying to keep it TOO simple. The world of jQuery can now be explored....

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page template should contain the `get_header();` function before the page content starts. If you don't want to include the header in this template then there should be a `wp_head();` function included at the top of the page.

The jQuery error occurs because you have not included the jquery.js library in this template. `wp_head()` contains all required JS and CSS libraries to include in the page.

```
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: temp_jQuery
* Template Post Type: Page
*/
?>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://stunninghikes.com/evenbetterhikes/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/resources/js/testjQuery.js'></script>
    <?php 
        get_header(); 
        /* OR */ 
        wp_head();
    ?>    
</head>



<body>
    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</body>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also you have to include `get_footer();` at the bottom of the template or `wp_footer();` at the bottom of the page if you are not including a footer on this template.

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to use the `$` as function parameter to define "$" as jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Or else you can try the below code :

```
(function($){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```